# Implementing Azure AD Authentication and Authorization in ASP.NET Using Group ID in C# .NET Framework

Tags: asp.net, microsoft-entra-id

I am working on an ASP.NET Web Forms project, and I need to implement Microsoft Entra ID authentication and authorization. Specifically, I want to restrict access to certain sections of my application based on the user's group membership.

I have already set up a Microsoft Entra ID application and obtained the necessary client ID, client secret, and other configuration details. Now, I need guidance on how to modify the authentication and authorization setup to grant access based on the user's group ID.

Key Requirements:

Authenticate users using Microsoft Entra ID.
Authorize users based on their group membership.
Restrict access to specific sections of the application based on group ID.
Implement the solution using C# and .NET Framework.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried following this guide? https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/convert-asp-net-webforms-with-windows-authentication-to-use-aad/

Comment: @ste-fu This documentation primarily focuses on ASP.NET Core, but I am working with the .NET Framework, not Core.

Comment: You can (generally) use the asp.net core tooling with .NET framework by changing the `<TargetFramework>` element in the project file to `net48`. Your can check the compatible version of the various packages on NuGet.org